# im use sort function for sort monodb data based on query provide

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman

```
const getAllProduct = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Clone the request query parameters to avoid modifying the original object
        const queryObj = { ...req.query };

        // Define a list of query parameters to exclude from the filtering process
        const excludeFields = ["page", "sort", "limit", "fields"];

        // Remove excluded query parameters from the cloned object
        excludeFields.forEach((el) => delete queryObj[el]);

        // Convert the filtered query object to a JSON string
        let querystr = JSON.stringify(queryObj);

        // Replace specific query operators with MongoDB-compatible syntax
        querystr = querystr.replace(/\b(gte|gt|lte|te)\b/g, (match) => `$${match}`);

        // Execute a MongoDB query using the modified query object
        let query = await Product.find(JSON.parse(querystr));

        // Check if a 'sort' parameter is provided in the request
        if (req.query.sort) {
            // Split and join the 'sort' parameter to create a sort string
            const sortBy = req.query.sort.split(",").join(" ");

            // Apply sorting to the MongoDB query
            query = query.sort(sortBy);
            console.log(query);
        } else {
            // If no 'sort' parameter is provided, sort by 'createdAt' in descending order
            query = query.sort("-createdAt");
        }

        // Execute the MongoDB query and send the result as a JSON response
        const product = await query.exec();
        res.json(product);
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle any errors that occur during the execution of the code
        throw new Error(error);
    }
});
```

im my code im trying to sort mangodb data based on provide query and this is api. but when i run my code its stuck on `query = query.sort(sortBy);`  and return error  :

```
{
    "message": "TypeError: The comparison function must be either a function or undefined",
    "stack": "Error: TypeError: The comparison function must be either a function or undefined\n    at C:\\Users\\91971\\Desktop\\node js\\controller\\productCtrl.js:87:15\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)"
}
```

have anyone idea how to slove i do chatgpt and bart and every ai tool not proper anser give me please help.

API run in postman.

Comment: The error is saying that you need to provide a function as an argument to the `sort()` method, not a value. See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#sorting_array_of_objects) for examples of how you can do this.

Comment: I already try this by crating loop function declare type as function.